# API.AI A bot that starts the conversation

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

I am just now creating my first bot for my own use, and I want 
to gather user information and search through my database for it.
I figured the best way for this is just to ask the question before the user 
starts the conversation. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this (getting the bot to send a message first)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger an event as soon as user comes to the chat bot platform - see https://api.ai/docs/events. Nearly all platforms triggers an event for users first time. Check the facebook bot docs.

Answer (score 0):

There is provision to do so in api.ai. The event is a feature that allows you to invoke intents by an event name instead of a user query. You just need to define event names for intents. Then, you can trigger these intents by sending a /query request containing an event parameter.